# I keep getting a use unresolved identifier error swift

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, error-handling

When I try to run this project I am greeted with a "Use of unresolved identifier error." Here is the code I get the error on the line with

```
var jsonDict =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
 as! NSDictionary
```

```
let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if((error) != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                let err: NSError?
                do {
                var jsonDict =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                } catch {
                if(err != nil) {
                    print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }

                else {
                    //5: Extract the Quotes and Values and send them inside a NSNotification
                    let quotes:NSArray = ((jsonDict.objectForKey("query") as! NSDictionary).objectForKey("results") as! NSDictionary).objectForKey("quote") as! NSArray
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotificationStocksUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: [kNotificationStocksUpdated:quotes])

                    })
                    }
                }

            }
        })
```

can someone please help. Thank you.

Comment: What line are you getting the error?

Comment: Yes, which line does it occur on?

Comment: @WMios I just updated the code to show where the error is

Comment: @LinkOpenheim I just updated the code to show where the error is

Comment: Have you defined your `data!` which is of `NSData` type?

Comment: Why are you doing your main logic in the Catch? That makes no sense. Do it in the Do block instead. The Catch is only for handling errors. And you're mixing Swift 1 with Swift 2 anyway (no need for `let err: NSError?`, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/223/reading-writing-json/821/nsjsonserialization).

Answer (score 0):

You problem could be this line of code in the `catch` block.

```
let quotes:NSArray = ((jsonDict.objectForKey("query") as! NSDictionary).objectForKey("results") as! NSDictionary).objectForKey("quote") as! NSArray
```

In the above statement `jsonDict` is out of scope. You declared jsonDict in the `do` block but are trying to use it in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

this cobweb of code is exactly why [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library exists. I recommend it highly, it can be imported into your project using cocoapods.

using this library the resultant code would be

```
jsonQuery["query"]["results"]["quote"]
```

which is more readable and as you implement more APIs, much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:-
(Assuming JSON has a root node structure)

```
let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: yourURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)



                    if let queries = json["query"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                            for query in queries {
                                if let quote = query["quote"] as? String {
                                        self.quoteArr.append(quote)
                                }

                            }//for loop
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                               // your main queue code 
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNotificationStocksUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: [kNotificationStocksUpdated:quotes])
                            })//dispatch

                    }// if loop

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                }

            }
            else
            {
                // No internet connection
                // Alert view controller
                // Alert action style default


            }
```